# Bash semicolon being equal to newline is not exactly true?

Tags: bash, shell

I've read in multiple articles that semicolon(`;`) in UNIX-like shells is equal to a new line.
However, the following is confusing me and I'm having no luck googling it either.

I'm guessing it's an issue with `do` in shell, but "bash semicolon do" is not exactly the most google-friendly search term combination.

Below is a simple `for` statement.

```
for i in {1..10}
do
echo "hi"
echo "bye"
done
```

As many Stack Overflow gurus have posted, every newline can be substituted with semicolons.

So.. we have this following "same" statement.

```
for i in {1..10}; do; echo "hi"; echo "bye"; done
```

and we get:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

What exactly is the semicolon? Is this just an unique issue with `do`?

Comment: AFAIK, it's pretty much a unique issue with `do` and `then` (from if..then). I can't think of another situation where you replacing a newline with a `;` fails (and heredocs are their own special thing where whitespace matters so that doesn't count). I'm ready to be corrected, though! =)

Comment: heredoc:  https://www.tecmint.com/use-heredoc-in-shell-scripting/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the [syntax of the `for`/`do` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for),

```
for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

we can see that `do` is followed by *`commands`* immediately, so using a newline after `do` doesn't replace a semicolon, but a space.

The description for [compound commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands) also says

> In most cases a list of commands in a compound command’s description may be separated from the rest of the command by one or more newlines, and may be followed by a newline in place of a semicolon.

but nowhere does it say that you can insert random semicolons. "Every newline can be substituted with semicolons" is simply too general a statement and not correct.

More manual evidence: in the section about [lists of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists), it says (emphasis mine):

> A `list` is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or a `newline`.
>
> Of these list operators, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, followed by `;` and `&`, which have equal precedence.
>
> **A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a `list` to delimit commands, equivalent to a semicolon.**

So a newline is equivalent to a semicolon *within a list of commands*.

Comment: thanks. It didn't occur to me that a newline can substitute semicolons and also spaces in certain contexts. It's still pretty confusing though. It's not like you can do `my_script.sh<press enter>params`. I guess newline \n can sometimes be substituted into spaces or semicolons but sometimes not?

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee I'd say the "empirical" guideline for when a newline and a space are interchangeable is "when the secondary prompt (typically `>`) is shown after you press enter", i.e., the shell expects your command to continue.

Answer (score 7):

It's not *just* with `do`; there are a number of contexts where the shell allows a newline where it would not allow a semicolon.

Here are most of them (leaving out the uses of newlines or semicolons inside quotes, which are always distinct from each other):

1. After `&&` or `||`

   ```
   some_command &&
   some_other_command
   ```
2. After a pipe (`|`):

   ```
   some_producer |
   some_consumer
   ```
3. Before the `in` in a `for` statement:

   ```
   for x
   in $(produce_values); do
   ```

   Although empty commands are illegal, the shell grammar does allow empty value lists in a `for` command, so `for x in; do do_something; done` is legal, and so would be the same thing written with newlines instead of semicolons.
4. Before or after the `in` in a `case` statement; also after the closing `)` of each pattern and the `;;` which closes each case:

   ```
   case $x
   in
   pattern)
     do_something ;;
   esac
   ```
5. After the keywords `if`, `then`, `elif`, `else`, `while` or `until`:

   ```
   if
     some_condition
   then
     do_something
   else
     do_something_else
   fi
   ```
6. After the `{` or `(` which opens a compound command or subshell:

   ```
   {
      a_command
      another_command
   }

   (
      a_command
      another_command
   )
   ```

   Similarly, after the `$(` which starts a command substitution:

   ```
   a=$(
     echo hello
   )
   ```

   In bash, this also applies to the `(` in process substitution: `<(...)`. See below for the slightly different handling in the bash extensions dealing with conditionals and arithmetic substitution.
7. After the `)` in a function definition:

   ```
   my_function()
   {
     do_something
   }
   ```
8. After the `;` or `&` which terminates a command:

   ```
   do_something;
   do_something_in_background &
   ```

   (Note that empty commands are illegal, so `do_something; ;` would be rejected.)

I took that list from the [shell grammar in the Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02). Bash allows newlines in other places; I couldn't think of any when I wrote this answer, but @BenjaminW reminded me:

- Inside a parenthesized array literal, either in an array assignment or an array declaration, newlines are considered whitespace:

  ```
  a+=(
    first_thing
    second_thing
  )

  local -A b=(
    [x]="value of x"
    [y]="value of y"
  )
  ```

And then I remembered these other pseudo-quoted environments:

- Bash also accepts newlines as whitespace inside arithmetic expressions:

  ```
  i=$((
     i + 
       3 * j
  ))

  if ((
    i + 3 * j
    >
    9
  ))
  ```

  and after the `[[` or before the `]]` in `[[`-style conditional statements:

  ```
  if
  [[
        $a -eq "done"
  ]]    
  then break
  fi
  ```

Comment: Additionally for Bash: in the declaration of arrays, `arr=(\nel1\nel2\n)` is okay, `arr=(;el1;el2;)` is not.

Comment: @benjaminW: Yeah, the parentheses in an array declaration are a kind of quoting. I forgot that one; thanks.

Comment: Especially for associative arrays (as in your example), using linebreaks makes for an order of magnitude improvement in readability, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanations. Man page is honestly torture, and I couldn't figure out how to search for this stuff. I guess I'd better get used to the man pages.

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee If you read a best practices guide like the highly recommended [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), you can follow the syntax and style in the examples and avoid most problems; your question already dives into the nitty-gritty. Which of course isn't a bad thing, but may be demotivating when starting out.

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee: You might well have the bash manual installed on your machine, where you can read it with `info bash`. If that just gives you the manpage, then you could try installing the `bash-doc` package, assuming a debian/ubuntu system. Or you can find it [online ](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)

Answer (score 0):

What @Benjamin W. explains in a quite exhaustive while lengthy answer can be summed up as a concise and simple general rule which also in my opinion sheds light on the reason behind the misunderstanding of this phenomena. What needs to be remembered is that:

##### In Bash

### Every **semicolon** CAN be substituted with a **newline**.

##### but

### Every **newline** CANNOT be substituted with a **semicolon**.

Here, `do <command>` is the original syntax. A *newline* can replace the space, but as a **semicolon** cannot replace a **newline**, we can't put a *semicolon* here.
However for the syntax `command1 ; command2`, a **newline** can replace a **semicolon** and give us

```
command1
command2
```

With time, we got much more familiar with a newline as the command-line separator instead of the semicolon and tend to see semicolons as a replacement for newlines in order to make one-liners, but it seems that bash was in fact designed the other way around: semicolons are the original separator, newlines are just syntactic sugar (in the context of the command-line separator).

NB: according to the explanations of Benjamin W.

Answer (score -2):

They work in zsh:
`for i in {1..10}; do; echo "hi"; echo "bye"; done`

`; for i in {1..10}; do; echo "hi"; echo "bye"; done`

`; for i in {1..10}; do; echo "hi"; echo "bye"; done;`

(Pay attention to the special case, and if you meet similar case, come back to this topic for details)

Comment: This is not the question asked. The topic is about understanding bash's behavior, not finding an environment where the syntax works